# How to get mailchimp Template ID?

Tags: php, api, mailchimp

I'm using mail chimp PHP API v2 and need to know `template_id` for use the `list` method.
http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/templates/update.php

There are no any clue to get specific template ID in mail chimp. How do i get this?

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve template ids through the "/templates/list.format" call.

link to the docs: http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/templates/list.php

Answer (score 1):

Just open your MailChimp Template and see the URL.

It should be something like:
`https://us5.admin.mailchimp.com/templates/editor?id=41`

`41` is your Template ID.